# MYSQL: Get two columns with default values and a third nomal column in a query

Tags: mysql

Here is the query I'm doing:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN study_id   = NULL THEN "" ELSE study_id END) AS id, 
       (CASE WHEN study_date = NULL THEN "" ELSE study_id END) AS sdate, 
       DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -25 DAY) AS daytick 
FROM tEyeResults WHERE DATE(study_date) = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -25 DAY)
```

This query will return the study_id, the study_date and the daytick column IF there there is a study_date that matches the one I'm searching for. If there aren't any rows such that the WHERE condition is met, then the query returns no rows.

What I want to do is modify it so that if there are no rows matching the WHERE condition, then a single row with the value "","",daytick is returned.

The case was my attempt to make this happen, but the query functions just as when I simply did:

```
SELECT study_id, 
       study_date, 
       DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -25 DAY) AS daytick 
FROM tEyeResults WHERE DATE(study_date) = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -27 DAY)
```

EDIT:

As per a suggestion in the comments I've tried this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(study_id, "") AS id, 
       COALESCE(study_date, "") AS sdate, 
       DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -25 DAY) AS daytick 
FROM tEyeResults WHERE DATE(study_date) = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -25 DAY)
```

Still get no rows as a result.

Comment: OT: `WHEN study_id   = NULL` is never true. Try `WHEN study_id  IS NULL` or better `SELECT COALESCE(study_id, "") AS id, ...`

Comment: Can your query return more than one row or is `study_date` unique?

Comment: syntax error or result? in first query you have INTERVAL -25 DAY (in where ) in second one you have INTERVAL -27 DAY

Comment: @trincot it is not. I expect to give more than one result whenever there are serveral studies in the same day.

Comment: @AliGhalambaz I get no syntax error. I need to try with 30 different intervals (I need to get the studies per day for the last 30 days)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a result set with just the daytick and outer join it with your table:

```
SELECT    COALESCE(study_id, "") AS id, 
          COALESCE(study_date, "") AS sdate, 
          daytick
FROM      ( SELECT DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -25 DAY) AS daytick ) ref
LEFT JOIN tEyeResults 
       ON daytick = DATE(study_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

from link [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31681541/mysql-case-not-working)
try like this

```
CASE study_id WHEN  NULL THEN "" ELSE study_id END
```

do not use column name like `CASE WHEN column=xyz` after WHEN

Comment: That wasn't really his problem.  The problem he had was that if there were no records that matched the date criteria that he got zero results. (obviously). While he still wanted it to return something.